# How to unit test promises in react/redux application

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, react-redux, chai

Looking at the advanced example on the [react-redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) site, what is the best way to unit test the `fetchPosts` function using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon`?  It uses a promise chain so in view of this, I have looked at `chai-as-promised`.

The promises chain together with the last one resolving to an empty value and dispatching an action to update the redux state.

App code:

```
export function fetchPosts(subreddit) {   
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
      return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))   
    } 
}

//other functions

export function requestPosts(subreddit){
    return {
        type:REQUEST_POSTS,
        subreddit
    }
}

export function receivePosts(subreddit,json){
    return {
        type:RECEIVE_POSTS,
        subreddit,
        posts:json.data.children.map(child => child.data),
        receivedAt:Date.now()
    } 
}
```

My attempt at unit testing:

```
describe('fetchPosts action creator', () => {
    it('should have one parameter', () => {
        expect(fetchPosts.length).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('should return a function holding one parameter', () => {
        let subreddit = 'frontend';
        expect(fetchPosts(subreddit).length).to.equal(1);
    });

   it('should execute the dispatch funcion with requestPosts' ,() =>{
       let spy = spy(dispatch);
       let subreddit = 'frontend';
       expect(spy.calledWith(fetchPosts(subreddit))).to.be.calledOnce;
       expect(spy.calledWith(receivePosts(subreddit,json))).to.be.calledOnce;
   })
})
```

My thoughts are

- Test `fetchPosts()` can hit the reddit api
- Check the response is valid json
- Check that `dispatch` is called twice with `requestPosts` and `receivePosts`

Comment: If you test that `fetchPosts` can reach the Reddit API, you are actually testing their site. If Reddit goes offline, your tests will fail. Instead you might want to mock the response, to simulate that the request was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [Asynchronous actions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store#asynchronous-actions) of [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store) package.

> A mock store for testing Redux async action creators and middleware. The mock store will create an array of dispatched actions that serve as an action log for tests.

Besides, you should stub the `fetch` and `Date.now()` functions.

This way it will not send HTTP requests through a real network and does not depend on real system time(local machine, CI/CD server) allowing your unit tests to run in an isolated, no side-effect environment.

E.g.

`actionCreators.ts`:

```
const REQUEST_POSTS = 'REQUEST_POSTS';
const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS';

export function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit));
    return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)));
  };
}

export function requestPosts(subreddit) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_POSTS,
    subreddit,
  };
}

export function receivePosts(subreddit, json) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
    subreddit,
    posts: json.data.children.map((child) => child.data),
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
  };
}
```

`actionCreators.test.ts`:

```
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { fetchPosts } from './actionCreators';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = createMockStore<{}, ThunkDispatch<{}, any, AnyAction>>(middlewares);

describe('46791110', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const store = mockStore({});
    const mRes = { json: sinon.stub().resolves({ data: { children: [{ data: 'jav' }, { data: 'big xx' }] } }) };
    const fetchStub = sinon.stub().resolves(mRes);
    const dateStub = sinon.stub(Date, 'now').returns(111);
    global.fetch = fetchStub;
    return store.dispatch(fetchPosts('nsfw')).then(() => {
      const actions = store.getActions();
      expect(actions).to.be.deep.equal([
        { type: 'REQUEST_POSTS', subreddit: 'nsfw' },
        {
          type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS',
          subreddit: 'nsfw',
          posts: ['jav', 'big xx'],
          receivedAt: 111,
        },
      ]);
      sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(fetchStub, 'https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw.json');
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(mRes.json);
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(dateStub);
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/46791110/actionCreators.test.ts (11.183 s)
  46791110
    ✓ should pass (5 ms)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 actionCreators.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.214 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/46791110